# Accessing other partitions

Tags: partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu.I want to know can I save my codes in other partitions(not the one where Ubuntu is installed).I tried using commands like cd    but it did not work.So my ques is can't I use other partition??Do I have to work only in home directory???

Comment: your other partitions are in ntfs type? if yes then you need to mount them first. Easy way: just click that partitions on unity launcher.

Comment: Still the same error-    'bash :cd: Study: No such file or directory'

Comment: Actuall y I have few c codes in this directory which I need to compile in the terminal,so I am using cd command to first go to that directory.But it is not working

Comment: can you post what command are you using/

Comment: You are on root(`/`) directory(`.../$`). Where is located your "Study" directory? is this a directory? To locating your "Study" directory, open file manager and goto your Study path and press <Ctrl>+<L> and copy the location of that and then switch to Terminal and type `cd` and one space then press <Ctlr>+<Shift>+<T> and hit enter. Is that worked?

Comment: Actually Study is not a directory,its an entire partition whose name is Study.I want to go to that partitoion.Like in Windows i simply type the drive letter of the partition to go to a partition.So I want to go to Study Partition and then goto other directories in this Study partition????

Comment: yes, you can not access directly into your partition with using their names. you have to type their mounted path that they are mount to `/media` directory. mostly they are mount to `/media/home/username/partitionnameORUUID/` location. and also you can get their mounted path from file manager under devices in left panel and pressing Ctlr+L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access directly into your partition with using their names. you have to type their mounted path that they are mount to `/media` directory. mostly they are mount to `/media/home/username/partitionnameOrUUID/` location. Also you can get their mounted path from file manager under devices in left panel and by clicking and opening them, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> you can see if where mounted and real location.